# Are there odd-dimensional vector spaces over infinite fields which are also fields?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

Algebra is extremely not my field, so excuse me if this is something obvious or silly, but I noticed something interesting today while I was looking at different ways to represent inner products spaces.

Observation 1: Every field $F$ is a vector space over itself, it is the vector space of $F$-dimension $1$

Observation 2: Sometimes a $2\le n$-dimensional vector space over an infinite field $F$ is *also* a field. For example, $$\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2,\sqrt3]=\Bbb Q+\Bbb Q\sqrt 2+\Bbb Q\sqrt 3+\Bbb Q\sqrt 6\cong\Bbb Q^4$$ is a field and a $4$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$, and $\Bbb C=\Bbb R+\Bbb Ri\cong\Bbb R^2$ is a field and a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb R$.

Observation 3: Every textbook example of a vector space over an infinite field $F$ which is itself a field is either $2^n$-dimensional or infinite-dimensional over $F$.

Questions: Are there odd-dimensional (of dimension $>1$) vector spaces over an infinite field which are also fields? What are some good examples? If not, then why not, is there a theorem?

Comment: There are degree 3 extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: You would also be interested in this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras).  Very close to what you're realizing.

Comment: @Randall What is an example of a degree 3 extension of $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: @R.Burton $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observation 3 is quite false; you can pick up any book on [algebraic number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_theory) for plentiful counterexamples. In general, a pair of fields $K \to L$ such that $K$ is a subfield of $L$ and $L$ has dimension $n$ as a vector space over $K$ is called a [field extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension) of degree $n$. Most interesting fields, and in particular $\mathbb{Q}$, have field extensions of every positive integer degree; for example, over $\mathbb{Q}$ the field extension $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ is cubic, with basis $\{ 1, \sqrt[3]{2}, \sqrt[3]{4} \}$.

To show that $\mathbb{Q}$ admits a field extension of every degree $n$ it suffices to exhibit an [irreducible polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) $f(x)$ of degree $n$, since then $\mathbb{Q}[x]/f(x)$ is the desired extension (with basis $\{ 1, x, \dots x^{n-1} \}$). This can be done in many different ways, for example using [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion), which tells us that we can take $f(x) = x^n - 2$. So $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[n]{2}]$ is the desired extension of degree $n$, with basis $\{ 1, \sqrt[n]{2}, \dots \sqrt[n]{2^{n-1}} \}$.

Comment: What is $\Bbb Q[x]/f(x)$?

Comment: @R. Burton: it can be defined in a couple of different ways. Abstractly it's a quotient ring: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring In this particular case an alternative definition that doesn't require quotients is the subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ generated by any root of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Either way, the standard terminology is that it is "$\mathbb{Q}$ adjoin a root of $f(x)$." You can learn more about this by reading a textbook on algebraic number theory or the Galois theory chapter of a textbook on abstract algebra.

Answer (score 2):

The answers to your question very much depend on *which* infinite field you are choosing as your ground field.

For the rational numbers $\Bbb Q$ there are field extensions $\Bbb Q\subseteq F$ of dimension $n$ for any $n\in \Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}$. Take for example $F=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]{2})$ or $F=\Bbb Q(t)$.

For the complex numbers $\Bbb C$ every proper field extension $\Bbb C \subsetneq F$ is infinite dimensional. This is because a field extension of finite dimension is algebraic, but $\Bbb C$ is algebraically closed, hence has no proper algebraic extensions.

The case of the real numbers is more delicate. If we have a field extension $\Bbb R\subseteq F$ of degree $n$ for some $n$, then it is algebraic. Thus it embedds into an algebraic closure of $\Bbb R$ and thus by uniqueness of algebraic closures up to noncanonical isomorphism into $\Bbb C$. We obtain a chain $\Bbb R \subseteq F \subseteq \Bbb C$ thus $F$ has to have dimension 1 or 2, since $\Bbb R \subseteq \Bbb C$ is 2-dimensional.

Probably you had in mind the theorem that the only finite dimensional $\Bbb R$-vector spaces, which can be equipped with the structure of a skew-field extending the multiplication of $\Bbb R$, are $\Bbb R$ itself, $\Bbb R^2$ in the case of $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb R^2$ in the case of the quaternions $\Bbb H$…